# how to convert object to array in javasscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to convert the object to an array, this is my object, I need to convert an array

```
{value1: prop1, value2: prop2, value3: prop3};
```

expected output

```
["value1": prop1, "value2": prop2, "value3":prop3]
```

I have tried my code below

```
var obj = {value1: prop1, value2: prop2, value3: prop3};
var arr = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             arr.push(key + ':' + obj[key]);
    }
};
```

getting wrong ouput please see below

```
["value1:prop1", "value2:prop2", "value3:prop3"]
```

expected out like below

```
["value1": prop1, "value2": prop2, "value3":prop3]
```

Comment: Your expected output isn’t valid JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good, this `.push` and object definition is just not working in Javascript as you would expect:

```js
var obj = {value1: 'aa', value2: 'bb', value3: 'cc'};
var arr = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             const newObj = {};
             newObj[key] = obj[key];
             arr.push(newObj);
    }
};

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is not a valid javascript syntax. There are a couple of ways to go about this, you could convert your object to a 2d array where the inline array holds the key and value of each field in the object.

```
var obj = {value1: prop1, value2: prop2, value3: prop3};
var arr = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         arr.push([key, obj[key]]);
    }
};
```

Output

```
[['value1', prop], ['value2', prop2], ['value3', prop3]]
```

If you're using javascript es2017, you can achieve the above result using `Object.entries(obj)`

Answer (score 0):

This method should not be possible as arrays do not have keys like in php, the keys in JS arrays are always numbers.

Arrays should look like this:

```
let array = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

And contained values are called with indexes:

```
// Just the value
array[0]

// Logging the value
console.log(array[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get an array of objects with single properties, you could take the entries and map new objects with a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
var object = { value1: 'prop1', value2: 'prop2', value3: 'prop3' },
    array = Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```